# Android studio 3.2.1 Layout editor preview disappearing when a tab is closed

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, preview

I am using Android Studio 3.2.1 and when I close a tab that is not the current one, the content of the preview window simply disappears, e.g.

Preview to close "Cupon" tab
[image: Normal]

After close "Cupon" tab
[image]

Comment: Yah, that's called **bug**. Just reopen preview tab and it'll be there or other best solution is to upgrade your studio & check it again.

Comment: Yah, i know that reopening the preview tab makes it visible again but i was just looking for a permanent solution :(

Comment: This happens due to rendering issues. Android Studio cannot render the layout sometimes and hence this. For now there is no permanent solution for this you will have to refresh it everytime you face this issue or work in design mode leaving it altogather :)

Comment: thanks @Umair , if you could answer with that comment i will check it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @karique answered the question you can accept it now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just switch the XML editor to tab `Design`, on the bottom left of the screen ...

there you have `Design` or `Blueprint` and even `Design + Blueprint`.

and I've just tried to reproduce the issue with Android Studio `3.3.0`:

- had to close all XML files before the `Preview` panel closed.
- nothing happened, when I've closed an associated Java class.

possible solutions:

- updating Android Studio to `3.3.0` might get you rid of that annoyance.
- also try to correct this one light-bulb marker on the `ConstraintLayout`.

to be honest... I've never used the `Preview` panel until now :)

Comment: turns out that the 3.3.0 version fixed that bug, after the update, the issue disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

This happens due to `rendering issues`. Android Studio cannot `render` the `layout` sometimes and hence this. This is a bug or it can be occurred due to low system specs but I believe google has to do something about it. For now there is no permanent solution, all you can do it is you will have to refresh it everytime you face this issue or work in design mode leaving it altogather.

Just one more thing whenever the rendering is failed most of the time there's a **`red`** warning sign on the top right of the design window if you click it, it will tell you the problem your layout is not being displayed.

[image]